# Is Velocitytools 3.0 out yet?

Tags: velocity, velocity-tools

For some time velocity engine 2.0 is out but the velocity tools is not upgraded yet.

As I understand it, velocity tools 3.0 will work with velocity engine 2.0.

The latstest in maven repo is velocitytools 2.0 but this one depends on velocity 1.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Latest [news](http://velocity.apache.org/news.html) is that you can just download [velocity tools 3.0 SNAPSHOT](https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/velocity/velocity-tools-generic/3.0-SNAPSHOT/)

> Note for Velocity Tools users: Velocity Tools 3.0 shall soon be released. Meanwhile, you are encouraged to use the Velocity Tools 3.x last snapshot (see Velocity Tools 3.x Upgrading notes).

And yes, velocity engine 2.0 is one of its [dependencies](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/dependencies.html):

> velocity   2.0+    Required for core infrastructure, ClassTool, LinkTool, LoopTool, RenderTool and XmlTool

**EDIT**

The test build of Velocity Tools 3.0 is available:

> No determination as to the quality ('alpha,' 'beta,' or 'GA') of Velocity Tools 3.0 has been made, and at this time it is simply a "test build". We welcome any comments you may have, and will take all feedback into account if a quality vote is called for this build.
>
> Release notes:
>
> - https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/dev/velocity/velocity-tools/3.0/release-notes.html
>
> Distribution:
>
> - https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/dev/velocity/velocity-tools/3.0/